# How to use Systemd for Django-q daemon

Tags: python, django

I use Django-Q for task queue and scheduler. I need to keep running the command: `python manage.py qcluster.`
How can I do it with Systemd?

I've found this code for .service file but I don't know how to use my Virtualenv for python path:

```
[Unit]
Description=Async tasks runner
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/django-admin qcluster --pythonpath /path/to/project --settings settings
User=apache
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who still have problem with this, Just follow these steps:

1. create a service, example:

> ```
> sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/qcluster.service
> ```

2. Edit service as follows:

> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=qcluster runner
> After=network.target
>
> [Service]
> User=user
> WorkingDirectory=/home/user/path_to_project
> ExecStart=/home/user/path_to_project_env/bin/python manage.py qcluster
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

3. Enable the service:

> ```
> sudo systemctl enable qcluster.service
> ```

4. Start the service:

> ```
> sudo systemctl start qcluster.service
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `django-admin` binary installed in your virtualenv's `bin` directory, or the `python` binary there to run `manage.py` within your project's working directory:

```
ExecStart=/path/to/my-venv/bin/django-admin qcluster --pythonpath /path/to/project --settings settings
```

or

```
ExecStart=/path/to/my-venv/bin/python manage.py qcluster --pythonpath /path/to/project --settings settings
RootDirectory=/path/to/project
```

Comment: I did what you said and the result:

`qcluster.service - qcluster runner
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/qcluster.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-01-05 19:04:29 CET; 3s ago
  Process: 2229 ExecStart=/home/user/project/env/bin/python manage.py qcluster --pythonpath /home/user/project --settings settings (code
 Main PID: 2229 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)`

Comment: Look at journalctl to see the details.

Comment: Thanks, It's running now.

Comment: What is the best way to tell that the qcluster is running after enabling it?

Comment: I'm trying to deploy Django-Q under a systemd service like you explain, but old threads never die and CPU raises 100% quickly. Is there any option in the service file I should add?

Comment: @P.Rodoreda Just follow The answer steps.