# How to make djangoQ run as a service using systemd

Tags: django, ubuntu

How to make DjangoQ run as a service using systemd?

There is a gap, djangoQ installation and running is like learning to run a Django project.
But now,
you want to push the project which is using [DjangoQ](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to production.

The problem is you are not aware of server and Linux, maybe you are even coming from Windows....

So can somebody tell us, How to run DjangoQ in ubuntu using systemd

I am getting the error that ExecStart path is not absolute...
I came from here:

[Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54053666/how-to-use-systemd-for-django-q-daemon)

But that answer is not complete, too much tacit knowledge unshared...

```
[Unit]
Description= Async Tasks Runner
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
ExecStart=home/shreejvgassociates/ot_britain_college/env/bin/python manage.py qcluster --pythonpath home/shreejvgassociates/ot_britain_college/OverTimeCollege --settin$
RootDirectory=home/shreejvgassociates/ot_britain_college/OverTimeCollege
User=shreejvgassociates
Group=shreejvgassociates
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I'm stuck at the same problem.

python manage.py qcluster is pretty straight forward but how do I make clusters run in the background whenever I need them?

cluster.start()
async_task(mytask)
cluster.stop()
Doesn't work. The cluster gets stuck in the stopping procedure and won't finish. Also the tasks are not executed. Might just go for the systemd solution here.

Answer (score 2):

It works well. Try it.

```
[Unit]
Description=Django-Q Cluster for site TestSite
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/test/TestSite/venv/bin/python3 /home/test/TestSite/manage.py qcluster

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```