# How to keep django-q run on ubuntu nginx server

Tags: python, django, django-q

I use ubuntu with nginx & gunicorn and try to run django-q

How can I keep django-q run when shutdown terminal please

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either run it as service ([refer to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54053666/how-to-use-systemd-for-django-q-daemon)) or use a process manager as described in the [documentation](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cluster.html#process-managers)