# Deploying Django project in an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have developed a Django website and hosted the application in an Amazon EC2 instance.
AMI name: ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-jammy-22.04-amd64-server-20231207
Instance type: t2.micro

I run the project following these steps:

1. SSH into the EC2 instance from my terminal.
2. I locate into the proper django project folder.
3. I run this command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Now, following these steps, I'm able to run the project and it works fine. But when I close the cmd opened in my local PC that I used to SSH into the EC2 instance and to run the application, then the application doesn't work anymore.
My aim would be to simply run the django project from my cmd once (of course after having SSH to the EC2) and then close my laptop and having the application still alive.

Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: Look at **Step 3.1** of [this page](https://www.programink.com/django-tutorial/django-deployment.html).  But again, Django's `runserver` is not meant for production environments.  So continue to **Step 3.2** as an example.  When deploying you will have to change the `ALLOWED_HOSTS`  and `DEBUG` in your **settings.py**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *nohup* for running it even after you terminate processes on your terminal/cmd.

```
nohup python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &
```

You can also log the output of above command by writing it to a file for debugging purpose.

```
nohup python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 & > runserver.out
```

Note: Not recommended for production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Please use Nohup

It ignores the hangup signal, allowing the process to continue running after the terminal is closed.

Steps :-

1. SSH into your Instance.
2. Navigate to the path where you have manage.py file.
3. Now run `nohup python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &`
4. You can exit the session now and you woulf

Run: nohup python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &.
The & at the end puts the process in the background.
Exit the SSH session; the process will continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's because when closing the ssh connection, you stop the program because it's run in foreground.

With the following command it should work:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &
```

PS: you should not start the Django application with a development server, see the [deployment page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/) of the Django documentation.

**edit** you could also create a systemd service like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70330425/11832127).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tryed to run the app with your command. But unfortunately when I close my cmd, the app doesn't work anymore